Are wallet addresses associated with a node?
I run a full node but I am relatively new (tech-wise).
I am aware that multiple wallet addresses can be created per node.
Can all wallet addresses on the node be seen (from the outside) as being associated with that particular node?
Or as far as the outside goes, do they just look like separate node?

No, generally addresses contain no information that links them together or to a specific node. However, surveillants may be able to make educated guesses by seeing which transactions a node rebroadcasts, or by analyzing the transaction graph to see which outputs got spent together.

From what I have read, Bitcoin Core implements countermeasures to make it much harder for other nodes or observers to tell which addresses are under its control. It makes it harder for others to tell which transactions are being relayed from other nodes and which originated in the node itself.

Does Bitcoin Core really use random delay in transaction relay?
Transaction Relay and trickling in Bitcoin
How are transactions propagated through the bitcoin network? (In-depth)

